# In vim insert mode:`ctrl-o` + `h` works differnt from `left arrow keys`

Tags: vim

**The task:**
input
`print("a")`

**What i expect:**
Type `p` `r` `i` `n` `t` `(` `)` `ctrl-o`  `h`
, then vim displays `print(|)`, in which `|` means the cursor.
Then type `"` `"` `ctrl-o` `h`  vim displays `print("|")`. Finally typing `a` will finish the task.

**But in fact**:
Typing `p` `r` `i` `n` `t` `(` `)` `ctrl-o`  `h`
results in `print|()`

**I know i can fix it by changing the first `h` to `i`**:
Type `p` `r` `i` `n` `t` `(` `)` `ctrl-o`  `i`
, then vim displays `print(|)`.
Then type `"` `"` `ctrl-o` `h`  vim displays `print("|")`. Finally typing `a` will finish the task.

Howerver, I feel uncomfortable because of the inconsistence between the ways of  inputting `()` and `""`.
**I want `ctrl-o` + `hjkl` works exactly as the `arrow keys` in insert mode.** Is there some way to fix the problem?

Comment: From `:help i_ctrl-o`, there's `ctrl-\ ctrl-o` that does what you're looking for ("like CTRL-O but don't move the cursor"). Not the most fluid combination to type frequently though, but you could remap `ctrl-o` (`:inoremap <C-o> <C-\><C-o>` should do the trick) to this maybe?

Comment: @Marth That is exactly what i want! thank you very much! I should have use the vim help.

Comment: `<Left>` is so much simpler and easier than anything you are trying to do.

Comment: @romainl It is logically. But moving to the arrow keys is not effiency in practice

Comment: In conclusion, putting `inoremap <C-o> <C-\><C-o>` in `.vimrc` solves the problem.